# Update row if certain columns are equal

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table of a custom object type.  I want to make it so when I add another instance, if there already exists a row  where certain columns match, then that whole old row is updated with the new one.

What's the best way of doing this?
Thanks